# Android 11 Write Access to sdcard/Android/someapp

Tags: android, scoped-storage

We are trying to migrate an app from 10 to 11 and this app modifies an XML file that is in another app's "sdcard/Android/someapp" dir. We have been browsing all over and there is a ton of stuff about this subject, none of which seem to give us write access this file any longer. This app works in 10 but not 11. We have requested the "manage all files" permission which seems to have been granted but still cannot read/write this any longer???
Here is our code to request the permission ... are we missing something?

```
        if (getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

            if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                try {
                    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
                    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                    intent.data = Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", applicationContext.packageName))
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2296)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    val intent = Intent()
                    intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2296)
                }
            }
        } else {
            //below android 11
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()){
                permissioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (permissioncheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_CODE);
                }

                permissioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (permissioncheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you will not be able to read from that directory. Google does not want it. It's privacy time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the bottom line is that you will NOT be able to WRITE to another apps external storage folder (/sdcard/Android/data/com.app.someapp) in And11+

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)+File.separator+"My App");` for creating app directiry required `Write external storage permission`?

Answer (score 0):

The Google modified the permissions on Android 11. A solution could be if you target the Android 10 (but Google won't enable to refresh your app)

You should change the permissions and write media storage:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Comment: So ... I tried to move the target SDK back to 29 and added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the manifest BUT still getting file not found eacces errors???

Comment: I think the target SDK downgrade not / not a good solution. I think you should use the Media store API. So you should save different files in different folders end requests based on media type (MediaStore.Images or MediaStore.Video or MediaStore.Audio). If you use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission with Android 11 target you have to use maxSDKVersion parameter: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="28" />`